# javascript to change language based on form input hidden value

Tags: javascript

I'm not really sure how to do this. I have a form with a language tag and I need to be able to have the 3rd party non editable text change to Spanish. In the form is a hidden field 
So

```
    if 
    <input type="hidden" name="lg" value="1">
    then 
    $("#continue_shopping").val("Sigue Explorando");
    $('#checkout_button a').text("Hagámoslo!");
    else
    $("#continue_shopping").val("Keep On Exploring");
    $('#checkout_button a').text("Let's Do This!");
```

I have the English side done and I'm sure there is cleaner code to use but I'm just using

```
    <script>
    $("#continue_shopping").val("Keep On Exploring");
    </script>
    <script>
    $('#checkout_button a').text("Let's Do This!");
    </script>
```

Any help pointing me in the correct direction would be great.
Thank you

3rd party page code...

```
    <div class="container">     
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
    <section id="cart_contents" class="fluid">  
    #cart_contents#                 
    </section>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-sm-3">  
    <section id="cart_details" class="fluid">
    #cart_upsell#
    #cart_shipping#
    #cart_tax#
    #cart_coupon#
    #cart_message#
    #cart_totals#
    #cart_validation#
    #cart_buttons#
    </section>
    <SCRIPT>
    $("#continue_shopping").val("Keep On Exploring");
    </SCRIPT>
    <script>
    $('#checkout_button a').text("Let's Do This!");
    </script>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You could use something like an array with field names to store your translations.

Comment: You can select attribute values using something like this: `$("[id=choose]")`. More info at [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp)